# what is the command to check list of upgradable packages in SUSE linux?

Tags: linux, upgrade, suse

in Ubuntu we use

```
apt list --upgradable
```

to get list of all upgradable packages in linux.
How we can check list of all upgradable packages in SUSE Linux.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of all new available packages.

```
sudo zypper list-updates --all
```

---

https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-sw-cl.html

Comment: The question is off topic and will be closed. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]